# how to install scala sbt( installing from a universal package,what is the next step after download ZIP file) in windows system

Tags: scala, sbt

there saveral ways to install scala sbt , I try to installing from a universal package, what is the next step after download ZIP file?

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation that the SBT project has graciously provided. If you run into issues that prevent your install from working on Windows then stackoverflow might be an appropriate place to ask.

Comment: @MarkKegel dude. did you even read the post? ... theyve graciously provided a lack of instructions. on the page youre talking about it literally says "download the zip and expand it" ... THEN WHAT???????? put it on your path? is there an .exe somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Windows link:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html

Here's a link that talks about installing SBT in UNIX and eventually running a word count program in Scala. The steps should be similar for Windows: http://www.codesynch.com/hadoop_spark_blog/sbt-scala-build-tool-unix-install-sbteclipse-plugin-sample-wordcount/